# Cartesian closed category isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Let be $$(B^{A})^{A'} \simeq B^{A \times A'}.$$  In any Cartesian closed category there is always an isomorphism but how to prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathrm{Hom}(Z, B^{A\times A'}) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(Z \times (A \times A'), B) 
\cong \mathrm{Hom}(Z \times (A' \times A),B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}((Z \times A') \times A, B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(Z \times A', B^A) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(Z, (B^A)^{A'})$

By the Yoneda lemma, we conclude $B^{A\times A'} \cong (B^A)^{A'}$.

Concretely, a morphism $B^{A\times A'} \to (B^A)^{A'}$ corresponds to a morphism $B^{A\times A'} \times A' \to B^A$, which corresponds to a morphism $B^{A\times A'} \times A' \times A \to B$. If for this last morphism you pick $eval:B^{A\times A'} \times (A \times A') \to B$, the first morphism $B^{A\times A'} \to (B^A)^{A'}$ is the canonical isomorphism.

Comment: Just as a note, this proof extends to any braided monoidally closed category and a very slight variant can be proven in any monoidally closed category.